# Unsure about two phrases dealing with location

Tags: phrases

I came up with these two phrases

> There isn't a mall in the same city as this bakery.

and

> There's no "Louis" barber in the mall belonging to same city as this bakery.

With the first one I would like to say that, in a certain city, there is a bakery (at least one) but no mall (at all).

With the second one I'm trying to say that in a certain city there is a bakery (at least one) and that in the same city there's also a mall (only one). And that in this mall there's no barber advertised as "Louis".

I can't avoid to feel that they are somewhat awkward. Especially the second one.

Do you think they could be rearranged to feel more natural?

Comment: They could and should be rearranged to feel more natural, preferably with help from somewhere such as English Language Learners.

Comment: Yep, they're awkward, especially the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first phrase is direct enough that it does not require a second or third reading to comprehend your intended meaning. Without context it is hard to understand your second sentence at all. It will probably be most beneficial to you to split your second sentence into multiple sentences.

"The bakery is in Chicago. There is no 'Louis' barbershop in the Chicago mall."

Or if you were to use a single sentence:

"The mall in the city with the bakery does not have a 'Louis' barbershop.

Comment: Pretty sure there's more than one mall in Chicago.